# Creating a script to move pictures to a folder taking the name of the picture

Tags: batch-file

Hello I'm trying to make a script to move almost 3000 pictures to folders, I want to move group of pictures:

> Example of name: 3a19gk-0-00-8hqGWOD

The group of the picture is: 3a19gk, the rest is the number of the picture.

I managed to make this one, but it's creating folder per picture. Any way to create folder taking just a part of the name?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath=D:\path
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.*) do (
  set "foldername=%%~nf"
  md "!foldername:~0,-3!" >nul 2>&1
  move "%%f" "!foldername:~0,-3!"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Any way to create folder taking just a part of the name?

You need a second (nested) `for /f` to parse the first part of the name.

Something like the following should work (warning untested):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath=D:\path
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.*) do (
  rem get the folder name up to the first hyphen
  for /f "delims=-" %%g in ("%%f") do (
    set foldername=%%g
    )
  md "!foldername!" >nul 2>&1
  move "%%f" "!foldername!"
  )
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the options of the `FOR` command so that you only need to use one `FOR` command. This shortens up the code a bit.

```
@echo off
pushd D:\path
for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%G in ('dir /a-d /b *.*') do (
    md "%%~G" >nul 2>&1
    move "%%~G-%%~H" "%%~G"
)
popd
```